# Function if alterar o css

Tags: css, funções, if

Boa tarde! Tenho um filtro em meu site que mostra certos parceiros da minha empresa, porém sempre que eu seleciono um filtro que possui poucas logos dos parceiros as divs ficam todas à esquerda.

Eu preciso de uma função que altere um atributo específico do meu css quando a pessoa fizer um filtro para que as imagens fiquem centralizadas.

Exemplo: Clicou em filtrar por segmento de "Segurança", seja alterado no CSS o atributo "width: 16.6%" para "width: 50.0%".

Sou leigo em programação ainda então fui eu mesmo que tentei fazer o script abaixo, não tenho certeza se o raciocínio está certo.

Index (botão do filtro):

```
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".seguranca">Segurança</a></li>
```

CSS (main.css):

```
#portfolio .portfolio-item {width: 16.6%;}
```

Script:

```
<script>
function(teste)
if (data-filter == .seguranca) {set style '.\main.css' = '.portfolio-item', width=50.0%}
</script>
```

Imagem (Parceiro):

```
<div class="portfolio-item seguranca">
   <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
      <img src="./images/imagem.png">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Cara tem uns detalhes no seu código, primeiro que vc tem que fazer um `preventDefault` no link que vc vai clicar para ele não mudar nada na página. Depois que no `data-atributi` vc colocou um `.` na frente do nome ".seguranca", não precisa desse ponto ai.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então na função do click vc faz um `setAttribut` e muda o `width` de 16% para 50%

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('[data-filter="seguranca"]');

function troca(e) {
e.preventDefault();
const img = document.querySelectorAll('.portfolio-item.seguranca');
img.forEach( function (e) {
    e.setAttribute("style", "width: 50%;")
})
}

btn.addEventListener('click', troca);
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
[data-filter="seguranca"] {
    color: red;
}
.portfolio-item  {
    width: 16%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
}
.portfolio-item  img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" data-filter="seguranca">Segurança</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="portfolio-item seguranca">
  <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
     <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/100">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="portfolio-item seguranca">
  <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
     <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/100">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Consegui fazer a troca do Width funcionar, porém só é aplicado na primeira imagem do filtro, as demais continuam com os 16.6%

Comment: @RogerWindberg é pq para pegar mais de um elemento vc precisa usar um querySelectorAll, e depois fazer um forEach. Editei o código olha ai

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando javascript puro eu faria assim:

```js
function changeWidth() {
   let divItem = document.querySelector('.portfolio-item img');
   divItem.style.width = "50%";
}
```

```css
.portfolio-item img {
  background: yellow;
  width: 16.6%;
}
```

```html
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".seguranca" onClick="changeWidth()">Segurança</a></li>


<div class="portfolio-item seguranca">
   <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
      <img src="https://dqzrr9k4bjpzk.cloudfront.net/images/16753616/1031279012.jpg">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: não funcionou, infelizmente.

Comment: voce chamou no onclick do seu botão? Cola aqui como voce chamou esse metodo pfvr

Comment: não sei como faz pra chamar o onclick, meu botão ta assim: <li><a href="#" data-filter=".seguranca">Segurança</a></li>

Comment: Entendi. Vou editar minha resposta pra ficar tranquilo pra você. Dai você coloca tudo no seu JS. Lembrando que estou considerando q seu .js vai estar devidamente importado.

Comment: Consegui arrumar o onclick, porém só a primeira imagem da linha ele coloca pra width 50%, as outras continuam como antes.

Comment: Feito, arrumei o código acima. Dá uma analisada. Como eu pego o elemento da imagem e altero ele diretamente, lembrando que você pode alterar outros elementos em conjunto. E se for array você pode utilizar parte da resposta do outro usuario tbm.

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer desta forma, onde você irá "filtrar" e alterar o `width` das divs de acordo com o valor do atributo `data-filter` do link clicado (veja comentários no código):

```js
// seleciona todos os links da ul
const filtro = document.querySelectorAll("#filtros a");
for(let i of filtro){
   i.onclick = function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); //  cancela a ação do click no link
      let f = this.dataset.filter; // pega o valor do atributo data-filter
      // seleciona todas as divs com a classe do atributo data-filter
      const dvs = document.querySelectorAll("#portifolio ."+f);
      // aplica a propriedade nas respectivas divs
      for(let d of dvs) d.style.width = "50%";
   }
}
```

```css
#portifolio { width: 300px; }
#portifolio .portfolio-item {width: 16.6%;}
#portifolio .portfolio-item img {width: 100%;}
.portfolio-item-inner{ display: flex; align-items: center; }
```

```html
<ul id="filtros">
   <li><a href="#" data-filter="seguranca">Segurança</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-filter="outra">Outra</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="portifolio">
   <div class="portfolio-item seguranca">
      <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
         <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg"> Segurança
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="portfolio-item outra">
      <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
         <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg"> Outra
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="portfolio-item seguranca">
      <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
         <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg"> Segurança
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```